# How to use Java get function on Thymeleaf HTML?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Follow up on this question
[Function to determine winner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138623/function-to-determine-winner)

How do I use the java function stated on the linked question in thymeleaf HTML form?

Here is the code I have so far, but the function call doesn't work:

```
    <tr th:each="score : ${score}">
        <td th:text="${score.player1name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${score.player2name}"></td>
        <td>
            <ul th:each="round : ${score.roundScores}">
                <li th:text="${round}"/>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td th:text="${score.finalscore}"></td>
<td th:text="score.winner : ${score.getWinningScore()}">
        <td th:text="${score.sportstype}"></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this score?')" th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${score.gameid})}">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary"  th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${score.gameid})}">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <a  href="/welcome" class="btn btn-success">New Game</a>
```

Here is the funtion I'm trying to call:

```
public String getWinningScore() {
    //Lambda Expressions to convert String array to Int array and calculate sums
    int sumOfscore1 = Arrays.stream(player1score).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
    int sumOfscore2 = Arrays.stream(player2score).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
    if (sumOfscore1 > sumOfscore2) {
        winner = player1name;
    } else if (sumOfscore2 > sumOfscore1) {
        winner = player2name;
    }
    return winner;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "score.getWinningScore()" (template: "scorelist" - line 31, col 8)

Comment: This expression: `score.winner : ${score.getWinningScore()}` is something I'd expect for a `th:each` -- not a `th:text`.  Why aren't you just doing `th:text="${score.getWinningScore()}"` or `th:text="${score.winningScore}"`.  The problem isn't with the getter.

Comment: <td th:text="${score.getWinningScore()}"></td> expression provides me the same type of error: Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "score.getWinningScore()" (template: "scorelist" - line 32, col 7) Could there be something wrong with my function?

Comment: The error message should tell you more... what does the entire stack trace say?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1UDbwXyb Link to full stack trace

Comment: Here is the important part: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` line number: `at hh.palvelinohjelmointi.urheilutilasto.domain.Score.getWinningScore(Score.java:118)`

Comment: int sumOfscore1 = Arrays.stream(player1score).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum(); It's this line. What I'm trying to do here is to change string type array to int array and calculate the sum of those. As far as I'm concerned, this is correct.

Comment: Haha... well, as evidenced by the stack trace, you must have a blank string in `player1score` that is causing the exception.  Debug it and see for yourself

Comment: @Metroids Thank you very much! This actually solved my problem. Apparently I had empty fields on my html front, and when less than max amount of rounds where played it filled the rest with blank string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need get, just try using `${score.winningScore}`

Comment: This provides me the following error: EL1004E: Method call: Method WinningScore() cannot be found on type...

Comment: Updated the answer by removing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had empty fields on my html front, and when less than max amount of rounds where played it filled the rest with blank string.

Blank string cannot be inputted to a string list.