# ParseInt throws NumberFormatExeption in a function. What is wrong with the function?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a function where I'm trying to parse a user input String array of 2 - 5 numbers to an Int array and calculate the sum of those numbers to determine a winner of a game. At this point it throws me a NumberFormatException.  Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Follow up to [How to use Java get function on Thymeleaf HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139564/how-to-use-java-get-function-on-thymeleaf-html)

Here are the java classes and the function...

```
public class Score {
    String player1name;
    String player2name;
    String[] player1score;
    String[] player2score;
}

//Function to determine winner
 public String getWinningScore() {
      //Lambda Expressions to convert String array to Int array and calculate sums
     int sumOfscore1 = Arrays.stream(player1score).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
     int sumOfscore2 = Arrays.stream(player2score).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
        if(sumOfscore1 > sumOfscore2) {
            winner = player1name;
        } else if(sumOfscore2 > sumOfscore1) {
            winner = player2name;
        } 
            return winner;
        }
```

...and the user input I have in thymeleaf Html.

```
        <input type="number" id = "a1s" name="a1" class="newMatch" value="0" min="0" max="11" th:field="*{player1score}">
        <input type="number" id = "b1s" name="b1" class="newMatch" value="0" min="0" max="11" th:field="*{player2score}">
```

Comment: what is throwing exception. your `getWinnerScore` or `thymeleaf`. Show your error trace .

Comment: Do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(player1score));` and share the output

Comment: I found the root of this error: The user can input 2 - 5 numbers depending on how many rounds are played. The input fields in Html sets the default value to "null" for some reason. Even when I have set the value="0". So my error actually lies in html. At the moment nothing presets the value to "0". Not th:value="0" nor value="0".